# Laraval notification property not found when using queueable trait

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have a notification that works fine:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;

class NewTransaction extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($transaction_detail)
    {
        //
        $this->transaction_detail = $transaction_detail;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
              ->subject('New Transaction Received')
              ->greeting('Hello ')
              ->line('Transaction '.$this->transaction_detail->reference.' has arrived.');
    }
}
```

However, when I insert the `queueable` trait

```
class NewTransaction extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined property: App\Notifications\NewTransaction::$transaction_detail
```

I have tried:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan queue:restart
php artisan queue:work
```

I have tried switching to the table driver but the jobs fail and I get the same errors in the `failed_jobs` table.

Comment: Add property initialization i.e. `private transaction_detail;` above constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to the constructor:

```
public $transaction_detail;

public function __construct($transaction_detail)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->transaction_detail = $transaction_detail;
    }
```

**Old**

Looks like you have a typo

```
class NewTransaction extends Notification <--
<-- { is missing
    use Queueable;
```

Comment: Yes sorry, that was just a typo in my question and not in my actual code.

Comment: @matt No problemos. See if the updated answer helps.

Comment: the problem persists :(

Comment: @matt you need to define the property before the constructor. I missed that.